# How to provide text in utf-8 with content-Type=multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, multipartform-data

I have a HTML form for images and text-input. The data is send to the server with the content-type="multipart/form-data". Unfortunately the text-input data is not in charset=utf-8 and certain characters are later not displayed correctly. How can I provide utf8 in a multipart/form-data request?

```
    const formdata = new FormData()
    formdata.append("name", "The great 5-$-Offer!") 
    formdata.append("file", imageData)
```

Comment: See [RFC 7578](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578), particular sections [4.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578#section-4.5) and [4.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578#section-4.6). However, it does not appear that the `FormData` API supports specifying a charset manually. But the client you are using to send the `FormData` should let you specify a default charset via `request.setRequestHeader()` or equivlent